# Commit file changes using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, string-comparison, gitpython

I want to overwrite a text file using Python and commit each iteration into a Git repo, so that I can analyze the file, seeing something like this for each commit:

```
-Number1
+Number2
```

I had the idea of using this code, but it doesn't really work:

```
repo = Repo(path).git
index = Repo(path).index

for x in range(10):
 with open(path2, "r") as f:
  content = f.read()
  repo.add(path2)
  index.commit(path2)
with open(path2, "w") as f:
  content = f.write("Number"+str(x))
```

Using gitk, it only shows changes in "Local changes checked in to index but not committed" but not like I wanted it in each commit.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Try to do in shell first. Then you could convert working shell script to a Python.